# Typescript performance multiple interface extending

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, styled-components

I'm creating a reusable component library to make my application development easier, and so that I don't have to look at CSS, I'm creating it so that the styles I need are controlled by the component's props. Each component is based on a base component with the props that each component needs to have.

Online [example](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/young-glade-forked-cs7t3j?layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq5f0jf700063p6fvaobqqji%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq5f0jf700023p6fscte79lv%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq5f0jf700033p6frwc8r7vb%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq5f0jf700053p6f2ornmyet%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clq5f0jf700023p6fscte79lv%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq5f0jf700023p6fscte79lv%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%257D%252C%2522clq5f0jf700053p6f2ornmyet%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq5f0jf700043p6fs6r4twgl%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522UNASSIGNED_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A0%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq5f0jf700053p6f2ornmyet%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clq5f0jf700043p6fs6r4twgl%2522%257D%252C%2522clq5f0jf700033p6frwc8r7vb%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq5f0jf700033p6frwc8r7vb%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15.132796880013814%257D)

Types shared across components etc.

```
// Orientation
export type TOrientation = "vertical" | "horizontal";

// Alignment
export type TVerticalAlignment = "top" | "bottom" | "center" | "stretch";

export type THorizontalALignment = "left" | "right" | "center" | "stretch";

// Borders
export type TBorderThickness = TQuadrupleValue<TLengthUnit>

export type TBorderRadius = TQuadrupleValue<TLengthUnit>

export type TBorderStyle = "dotted" | "solid" | "double" | "dashed";

// Margin, Padding
export type TMargin = TQuadrupleValue<TLengthUnit>
export type TPadding = TQuadrupleValue<TLengthUnit>

// Overflow
export type TOverflow = TDoubleValue<"auto" | "visible" | "scroll" | "clip" | "hidden">;

// Units
export type TLengthUnit =
  `${number}cm` |
  `${number}mm` |
  `${number}in` |
  `${number}px` |
  `${number}pt` |
  `${number}pc` |
  `${number}em` |
  `${number}ex` |
  `${number}ch` |
  `${number}rem` |
  `${number}vw` |
  `${number}vh` |
  `${number}vmin` |
  `${number}vmax` |
  `${number}%`;

// Generic
export type TDoubleValue<T extends string | number | undefined> = 
  T |
  `${T} ${T}`;

export type TTripleValue<T extends string | number | undefined> = 
  T |
  `${T} ${T}` |
  `${T} ${T} ${T}`;

export type TQuadrupleValue<T extends string | number | undefined> =
  T |
  `${T} ${T}` |
  `${T} ${T} ${T}` |
  `${T} ${T} ${T} ${T}`;
```

Base component:

```
import styled from "styled-components";
import { TBorderRadius, TBorderStyle, TBorderThickness, THorizontalALignment, TLengthUnit, TMargin, TOrientation, TOverflow, TPadding, TVerticalAlignment } from "../lib/types";

export interface IBaseComponentProps {
  width?: TLengthUnit;
  minWidth?: TLengthUnit;
  maxWidth?: TLengthUnit;
  height?: TLengthUnit;
  minHeight?: TLengthUnit;
  maxHeight?: TLengthUnit;
  margin?: TMargin;
  padding?: TPadding;
  parentOrientation?: TOrientation;
  verticalAlignment?: TVerticalAlignment;
  horizontalALignment?: THorizontalALignment;
  borderStyle?: TBorderStyle;
  borderColor?: string;
  borderThickness?: TBorderThickness;
  borderRadius?: TBorderRadius;
  background?: string;
  boxShadow?: string;
  backdropFilter?: string;
  filter?: string;
  opacity?: number;
  zIndex?: number;
  overflow?: TOverflow;
}

export const StyledComponent = styled.div<IBaseComponentProps>`
width: ${({width}) => width};
min-width: ${({minWidth}) => minWidth};
max-width: ${({maxWidth}) => maxWidth};
height: ${({height}) => height};
min-height: ${({minHeight}) => minHeight};
max-height: ${({maxHeight}) => maxHeight};
margin: ${({margin}) => margin};
padding: ${({padding}) => padding};
align-self: ${({parentOrientation, verticalAlignment, horizontalALignment}) => getAlignment(parentOrientation, verticalAlignment, horizontalALignment)};
border-style: ${({borderStyle}) => borderStyle};
border-color: ${({borderColor}) => borderColor};
border-width: ${({borderThickness}) => borderThickness};
border-radius: ${({borderRadius}) => borderRadius};
background: ${({background}) => background};
boxShadow: ${({boxShadow}) => boxShadow};
backdrop-filter: ${({backdropFilter}) => backdropFilter};
filter: ${({filter}) => filter};
opacity: ${({opacity}) => opacity};
z-index: ${({zIndex}) => zIndex};
overflow: ${({overflow}) => overflow};
`

function getAlignment(parentOrientation: TOrientation | undefined, verticalAlignment: TVerticalAlignment | undefined, horizontalALignment: THorizontalALignment | undefined):string | null {
  const verticalMap: Readonly<{ [key in TVerticalAlignment]: string }> = {
    top: "flex-start",
    bottom: "flex-end",
    center: "center",
    stretch: "stretch"
  }

  const horizontalMap: Readonly<{ [key in THorizontalALignment]: string }> = {
    left: "flex-start",
    right: "flex-end",
    center: "center",
    stretch: "stretch"
  }

  if (parentOrientation === "horizontal" && verticalAlignment !== undefined) {
    return verticalMap[verticalAlignment];
  }

  if (parentOrientation === "vertical" && horizontalALignment !== undefined) {
    return horizontalMap[horizontalALignment];
  }

  return null;
}
```

Example component:

```
// StackPanel.styled.ts styled component file

import styled from "styled-components";
import { IBaseComponentProps, StyledComponent } from "../Component.styled";
import { TLengthUnit, TOrientation } from "../../lib/types";

export interface IStyledStackPanel extends IBaseComponentProps {
  orientation?: TOrientation;
  spacing?: TLengthUnit;
}

export const StyledStackPanel = styled(StyledComponent)<IStyledStackPanel>`
display: flex;
flex-direction: ${({orientation}) => getOrientation(orientation)};
gap: ${({spacing}) => spacing};
`

function getOrientation(orientation: TOrientation | undefined): string {
  const map: Readonly<{ [key in TOrientation]: string }> = {
    vertical: "column",
    horizontal: "row"
  }

  return map[orientation || "vertical"];
}

StyledStackPanel.displayName = "StyledStackPanel";

// StackPanel.tsx component file

import React from "react";
import { IStyledStackPanel, StyledStackPanel } from "./StackPanel.styled";

interface IStackPanel extends IStyledStackPanel {
  children?: React.ReactNode;
}

export const StackPanel: React.FC<IStackPanel> = ({children, orientation = "vertical", ...rest}) => {
  return (
    <StyledStackPanel orientation={orientation} {...rest}>
      {React.Children.map(children, (child) => {
        if (React.isValidElement(child)) {
          return React.cloneElement(child as React.ReactElement, {parentOrientation: orientation})
        }

        return child;
      })}
    </StyledStackPanel>
  )
}
```

With such an implementation, I encountered the fact that typescript showing the type after hovering the mouse over the variable became longer and loading often appears at the beginning, and adding the correct types to variables or expanding the interface only after a long time removes the underline of the error. Typescript checking also takes much longer. In my opinion, my reasoning is good and the way I want to do it is ok, but I'm not sure.

Maybe this is a stupid question, but I preferred to ask more experienced people whether I should change something, whether it looks good and correct, and whether I should worry about these typescript "complaints" before I start writing larger and more complex components.

Comment: Assuming this really is a [mre] (in that you can't demonstrate the issue with anything shorter), could you possibly reproduce in a web IDE and give us a link to it?  I don't know if anyone's going to go through the trouble of copying this code into a new project themselves just to see what's happening... and that decreases your chance of getting an answer that someone actually tested and verified (as opposed to just conjecture).

Comment: @jcalz Sorry, here is the [link](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/young-glade-forked-cs7t3j?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.tsx). I just don't know if you'll be able to see what exactly I mean here. However, I mainly wanted to "assess" this code in terms of correctness and performance

Comment: Tangential: You're missing some [CSS length units](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units#lengths) in `TLengthUnit`.

Comment: @jsejcksn It's true, I left out a few, I took the units from [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.php), but I won't even use some of them, I only gave them just in case, so I have no intention of extending this type ;)

Comment: From a brief glance I'd say the problem is you're generating huge unions; but you could almost certainly reduce this to a true [mre] just by generating the big unions and demonstrating the issue in a single snippet of code instead of a full project.  If you do that you'll probably get more useful engagement.  Generally speaking huge unions can often be avoided by making things more generic, but I'm not inclined to try to refactor a project.  I'll check back if I see a more manageable [mre] here.  Good luck!

Comment: @jcalz I may have constructed the question incorrectly, but the main idea was to find out whether my approach is good, whether such a basic component is a good idea and whether it will cause any performance problems.